# how to create soap server using php to return xml message of a structure as follows:

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, zend-framework

what's the best approach to create soap server using php either with zend or without
to return xml message of a structure as follows:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<response>
<element2>
      <element3>
    <element4>
        <element5>
            <element6>

                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .

            </element6>
        </element5>
    </element4>
</element3>
</element2>
</response>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I need an approach to create php classes,and instantiate big object that consists of another objects, thats returned in an xml format shown as above to the client
Thats what on mind.. I need suggestions and best practices.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the names of the XML tags in your response by using a SoapVar

```
return new SoapVar(
            array(
                'Element1' => "Some value",
                'Element2' => "Some other value"), SOAP_ENC_OBJECT );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use PHP built-in [SOAP server class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php)

Comment: I know how to use the class for just creating simple server, but i want an approach about how to instantiate objects of different classes, and merge them together in a big one